# XAMPP and disabled advanced features

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Absolutely cannot get rid of these errors in phpmyadmin Version information: 4.2.11

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] ...   not OK [ Documentation ]
Configurable menus: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] ... not OK [ Documentation ]
Hide/show navigation items: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
Saving Query-By-Example searches: Disabled

I have tried the following:
ran SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_users` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`usergroup`)
) 
  COMMENT='Users and their assignments to user groups'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_usergroups` (
  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tab` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `allowed` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`usergroup`,`tab`,`allowed`)
) 
  COMMENT='User groups with configured menu items'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_navigationhiding` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `item_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`item_name`,`item_type`,`db_name`,`table_name`)
) 
  COMMENT='Hidden items of navigation tree'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Then updated my config.inc.php with

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma_users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma_usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma_navigationhiding';
```

Then flushed table caches and restarted phpMyAdmin. The tables for pma_users and uaergroups have been created, but I still get the errors.

PLEASE HELP! This is causing serious issues with my drupal functionality.
Note, I have not yet set root or pma_user passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately my solution to this problem was to move away from XAMPP local hosting. I moved my site files to remote server, and installed my database and imported my database to their phpyadmin without any issue. Site is now connecting and working beautifully. Spending countless hours following every post I could find and referring to the phpmyadmin documentation were to no avail as opposed to just abandoning ship and going with potentially a more novice user like myself. This worked for me because the remote hosting option was a viable. Unfortunately this answer is not helpful to those whom still need local hosting environment and are using XAMPP. I have the Aquia Dev Desktop that included XAMPP with great success in the past and maybe good option some.